# Are there any CS-trees named after flora-trees?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, reference-request, trees

This is meant to be a fun question, and I hope it's not too off topic. Is there a defined mathematical object or data structure that has a name collision with a type of physical tree in the real world?

In computer science we have red-black trees, B-trees, quadtrees, and so on. In the biological sense of the word tree, we have palm trees, pine trees, redwood trees, etc.

My question: is there a word $w$ such that a $w$ tree could refer to a physical tree in the real world, or a mathematical object?

Comment: I would give *aspen* tree as an answer, except that the structure that the authors describe isn't actually a tree. http://conferences.sigcomm.org/co-next/2013/program/p85.pdf

Comment: It's not quite what you want, but there is a graph-theoretic *cactus*.

Comment: I guess "rooted tree" does not count?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question either, but this paper borrows liberally from the terminology of forestry management in the service of managing trees, in a typical Phil Wadler way.  http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/deforestation.html

Comment: I was sorry to find out that people using attributed grammars do not even
call Xmas trees their trees decorated with attributes.

Comment: @babou. Mixed <giggle>s and <groan>s.

Comment: now that would be a good one indeed, and may i add, possibly relate to computational issues of botanic science itself :)

Answer (score 4):

Robert Tarjan defines the *palm tree* in ["Depth-first search and linear graph algorithms"](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~gilbert/cs240a/old/cs240aSpr2011/slides/TarjanDFS.pdf) (1972):

> Let $P$ be a directed graph of two disjoint edge sets, denoted 
>   $v \rightarrow w$ and $v \overset{-}{\rightarrow} w$ respectively. If $P$
>   satisfies the following properties:
>
> 1. The subgraph $T$ containing the edges $v \rightarrow w$ is a
>       spanning tree of $P$;
> 2. Each edge not in $T$ connects a vertex with one of its ancestors in
>       $T$.  The edges $v \overset{-}{\rightarrow} w$ are called the *fronds* of $P$.

e.g.,

[image: Palm Tree]

He goes on to prove that the directed graph generated by a depth-first search of a connected graph is a palm tree.

In [Collective Tree Spanners and Routing in AT-free Related Graphs](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2006/DraganYanCorneil2006.10.2.pdf), Dragan, Yan, and Corneil  construct a specific spanning tree that they call a *willow-tree.*

Answer (score 3):

How about a [banana tree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BananaTree.html)? The organic kind are colloquially, but not botanically, [trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree).